# DB2 SQL - add order line number and total lines per order

Tags: sql, join, db2, db2-400

I have a sales order header and detail file that joins together to give me this:

```
Order_No  Item 
99998     AA 
99998     AB
99998     AC
99998     AD
99999     AA
99999     AD
```

With this SQL I can show total lines per order:

```
SELECT 
HDR_ORDERNO as OrderNo
DET_ITEM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM HEADER
   WHERE HDR_ORDERNO = DET_ORDERNO) as Total_Lines
FROM
DETAIL LEFT JOIN HEADER
ON (HRD_ORDER = DET_ORDER)
ORDER BY 
HDR_ORDERNO,
```

I would like to add rows for Line_Number for each order to give me this:

```
Order_No  Line_Number  Total_Lines  Item 

99998    1             4           AA 
99998    2             4           AB
99998    3             4           AC
99998    4             4           AD
99999    1             2           AA
99999    2             2           AD
```

I am using IBM DB2/SQL, So your fancy MS-SQL and Oracle syntax won't work here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ROW_NUMBER() OLAP function is your friend...added to DB2 for IBM i at v5r4...

```
with dtl_cnt as (select det_orderno
                        , count(*) as tot_lines 
                 from detail
                 group by det_ordno)
select 
 hdr_orderno
 , row_number() over (partition by hdr_orderno) as Line_no
 , dc.tot_lines
 , d.item
from
  header 
    join dtl_count dc on hdr_orderno = dc.det_orderno
    join detail d on hdr_orderno = d.det_orderno
```

Comment: Syntax error because the CTE doesn't have a `GROUP BY` to go with the aggregate function.

Comment: Gezz...that's what I get for trying to answer a question before bed.  Answer was missing the FROM is the CTE also.  I've added both.

Comment: Gezz...that's what I get for trying to check an answer to a question before bed.  Can't believe I missed mentioning the `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with similar answer... Other than subselect, I think it's about the same..

```
SELECT    
   ORDER_HED.ORDER_NUM, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*)      
       FROM ORDER_DET  
       WHERE ORDER_HED.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_DET.DETAIL_NUM) as 
   LINE_COUNT,  
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY DETAIL_NUM ORDER BY DETAIL_NUM ASC) as 
   ROW_NUMBER,  
   ORDER_DET.DETAIL_SKU,  
   ORDER_DET.DETAIL_QTY, ORDER_DET.DETAIL_PRICE 
FROM ORDER_HED JOIN ORDER_DET  
ON(ORDER_HED.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_DET.DETAIL_NUM)
```

Note, field names are a bit different.

Comment: The one problem with this is the subselect is likely being run for each row, which can be a performance issue.  Doing it as a CTE is going to get it to run once.  Oh, partitioning and ordering by the same column will have no effect: the `ROW_NUMBER` restarts each time the partition changes, so each different `DETAIL_NUM` starts at 1 anyways.